# Windows control message constants

Tags: winapi

This is probably a ridiculous question but could anyone point me in the right direction for getting the numeric values representing the messages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I've looked in the Commctrl.h files I've found on the net but none seem to offer the values, obviously from trial I can determine some like right click is 4294967291 and left is 4294967294.

Edit:

@Remy Lebeau, so I subclassed the parent of the list view then caught the WM_NOTIFY and the hWndFrom is the list view and moving the mouse on to the list view then right clicking outputs to the debug window:

```
 4294967146
 4294967175
 4294967175
 4294967280
 4294967196
 4294967289
 4294967291
 4294967284
 4294967146
```

from the code item of the NMHDR structure, this is the Lua print function outputting the code so I'm assuming that Lua is converting the dec/hex so am I doing something badly wrong here? I got a good copy of Commctrl.h from a trial of Visual Studio and took your advise and got the codes I needed anyway so thanks.

Comment: Write a program in C++ that includes `commctrl.h` and prints out all the values. Paste the message names into a constant array declaration and loop over it. Should be 5-10 minutes work. I guess you need this because you want to translate some code to a different language. Perhaps it would be helpful to tell us what's begind the question.

Comment: `4294967291` is `0xFFFFFFFB`, and `4294967294` is `0xFFFFFFFE`, neither of which is a valid window message ID, let alone any kind of right/left click messages. Where are you getting these values from?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here because the messages you linked to are messages you *send*, not messages you *receive*.

Comment: David Heffernan, Im using a Lua module to access user32.dll. Remy Lebeau, I subclased the parent window and got the codes from debugging so when I right clicked the control only 4294967291 was sent. Raymond Chen, so do I define these myself then?

Comment: Like I said, 4294967291 is not a valid window message ID. A right-click would generate `WM_RBUTTONDOWN` (0x204 hex, 516 dec), `WM_RBUTTONUP` (0x205 hex, 517 dec), and `WM_CONTEXTMENU` (0x7B hex, 123 dec) messages to the ListView itself, and a `WM_NOTIFY/NM_RCLICK` (0x4E hex, 78) message to the parent window. 4294967291 is 0xFFFFFFFB, which is a 32-bit sign-extended version of an 8-bit 0x7B value, but you should not be getting window message ID as 8-bit values to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of those messages are defined in `Commctrl.h`, which you can view in any text editor.  ListView messages are positive offsets from `LVM_FIRST`, which is defined in that same file as `0x1000` (decimal 4096), eg:

```
#define LVM_FIRST               0x1000      // ListView messages

#define LVM_GETBKCOLOR          (LVM_FIRST + 0)
#define LVM_SETBKCOLOR          (LVM_FIRST + 1)
#define LVM_GETIMAGELIST        (LVM_FIRST + 2)
...
#define LVM_GETNEXTITEMINDEX    (LVM_FIRST + 211)
```

Comment: To clarify:  This answer is about messages sent to a list view control.  The question, as edited, is about the codes in the NMHDR of the WM_NOTIFY messages sent by a list view control to its parent window.  Those are large numbers because those codes are defined as negative offsets from 0 but are interpreted as unsigned integers.  As with the messages, the notification codes can also be found in CommCtrl.h.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy this answer was in response to the original question. If you look at the edit history of the question, you will see it was edited after this answer was posted.

Comment: Yep.  I tried to acknowledge that with the "as edited" bit.  I'm just trying to provide context for those who just land here looking for an answer to the question as it stands today.  It was not intended as a criticism of the answer.  You still have my upvote because it still boils down to "look in CommCtrl.h."

Answer (score 2):

[Replaced entire answer to be consistent with the clarified question.]

The `LVM_...` values are window messages that can be sent to a list view control.

The `LVN_...` values are notification codes specific to list view controls.

Controls that send `WM_NOTIFY` messages to their parent window use notification codes in the `NMHDR` to indicate the type of notification.

CommCtrl.h defines the values used for the codes in the `NMHDR`.  There is a range of general purpose notification codes that may be sent by any control, and there are ranges of notifications that are specific to the type of control sending it.  Here are a few:

```
#define NM_FIRST                (0U-  0U)       // generic to all controls
#define NM_LAST                 (0U- 99U)

#define LVN_FIRST               (0U-100U)       // listview
#define LVN_LAST                (0U-199U)

#define HDN_FIRST               (0U-300U)       // header
#define HDN_LAST                (0U-399U)
```

Notice that these are negative offsets from zero, but they're interpreted as unsigned values, which is why you saw the large positive values.  I believe this is done so that, if you wanted to make a custom control, you could define its notification codes as `(NM_FIRST + x)` and know that they won't collide with the codes from the system-provided controls.

Very old controls, like buttons, typically send general window messages, like `WM_COMMAND`, to notify them of state changes.  In or around the Windows 95 timeframe, Microsoft introduced the "common controls" library, and those controls took a unified approach to notifications.  Instead of inventing many new control-specific window messages, these controls primarily use the `WM_NOTIFY` message to send notifications to their parents.

The `LPARAM` of the `WM_NOTIFY` message is a pointer to a data structure with the details of the specific notification.  These structures all start with a notification message header (`NMHDR`).  The `NMHDR` has a `code` field that tells the receiving window the type of notification being sent, which implies what data lies beyond the `NMHDR`.

For example, if you're a parent of a list view control, and it sends you a `WM_NOTIFY`, you first interpret the `LPARAM` as a `NHMHDR *`.  Now you can read the `code` member of that `NMHDR`.  Suppose it's `LVM_ITEMCHANGED`.  You can re-interpret the `LPARAM` as an `NMLISTVIEW *` (because the [documentation for `LVM_ITEMCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvn-itemchanged) says so).  The `NMLISTVIEW` gives you access to the details of that notification.

[Note that there's also a `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message that child windows might send to their parent window.  Despite the name, those are mostly unrelated.]

Answer (score 2):

You can try installing any of the Python bindings for the WinAPI, for example [this one](https://code.google.com/p/pywingui/source/browse/trunk/pywingui/comctl.py?r=30&spec=svn32).

In the source, the numbers are not easily visible, but you can import them in your Python interpreter and see them:

```
> python
>>> import comctl
>>> comctl.LVM_GETVIEW
4239
```

Or if you want all of them together, you can write a script:

```
import comctl
for n in dir(comctl):
    if n.startswith('LVM_'): # or whatever prefix you want
        print n, '=', getattr(comctl, n)
```

Comment: I'm loving that script to spit them all out. Nice work.